# Changing link color in Trillian Astra's message window

Tags: colors, window, trillian

how can I change the color of links what are in a message window in Trillian Astra?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be much you can do in the way of customizing Astra's look via the preferences dialogs.  I guess they expect you to make your own [skins](http://developer.ceruleanstudios.com/index.php/Astra_Tutorial).